# Check that a variable is an instance of a Class Object in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, instance-variables, orders, object-class

I am running a function whereby I check if a user has a refunded item/s on their previous order and if they do then apply a credit as a negative cart fee at checkout. The function is working for users who have placed an order before but **is causing a critical error** on the site for new users.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_refunds() on bool in /wp-content/themes/my-theme/refunds.php:20 Stack trace:  
#0 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(287): add_last_order_refund_total_at_checkout(Object(WC_Cart))  
#1 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)  
#2 /wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)  
#3 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php(1714): do_action('woocommerce_car...', Object(WC_Cart))  
#4 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(270): WC_Cart->calculate_fees()  
#5 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php(829): WC_Cart_Totals->get_fees_from_cart()  
#6 /wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc- in /wp-content/themes/my-theme/refunds.php on line 20
```

Here is the code to check for any refunds on the previous order:

```
//Check total of refunded items from last order - add as a fee at checkout
function add_last_order_refund_total_at_checkout($cart_object){
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // The current user ID
    $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
    $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();
    $order_id = $last_order;

    // Get the WC_Order Object instance (from the order ID)
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Get the Order refunds (array of refunds)
    $order_refunds = $order->get_refunds();
    $total_to_refund = $order->get_total_refunded()*(-1);//WIP need to check which items have tax
    
    if (!empty($order_refunds)) WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Refund', $total_to_refund  );  
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_last_order_refund_total_at_checkout', 10, 1 );
```

I believe I need to first check to see if a user has any previous orders otherwise the get_refund() is causing an error as their aren't any orders to check? How would I safely do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look to `WC_Customer` `get_last_order()` method [documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Customer.html#_get_last_order)  or [source code](http://WC_Customer), you will see:

```
/*
 * @return WC_Order|false
 */
```

which means that `get_last_order()`  method can return **alternatively**:

- the `WC_Order` object
- or `false` boolean value.

So you can just use in your code:

```
$last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

if ( ! $last_order )  {
   return; // Exit (Not an order)
}
```

To avoid this error.

---

Now you can use [`is_a()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-a.php) php conditional functions to check that a variable  is a from a specific Object class and not something else like:

```
$last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

if ( ! is_a( $last_order, 'WC_Order' ) ) {
   return; // Exit (Not an order)
}

// Your other code…
```

Or you can use  [`method_exists()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) php conditional functions for `WC_Order` `get_refunds()` method, to check that the a variable is a from a specific Object class  and not something else:

```
$last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

if ( ! method_exists( $last_order, 'get_refunds' ) )  {
   return; // Exit (Not an order)
}

// Your other code…
```

The three cases work nicely, avoiding an error

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try this way, multiple controls have been added, see comments

```php
// Check total of refunded items from last order - add as a fee at checkout
function add_last_order_refund_total_at_checkout( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // The current user ID
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    
    // User id exists
    if ( $user_id > 0 ) {
        $customer = new WC_Customer( $user_id );
        
        // Get last order
        $last_order = $customer->get_last_order();

        // True
        if ( $last_order ) {

            // Get the order id
            $order_id = $last_order->get_id();
        
            // Order ID exists
            if ( is_numeric( $order_id ) ) {
                // Get the WC_Order Object instance (from the order ID)
                $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

                // Get the Order refunds (array of refunds)
                $order_refunds = $order->get_refunds();
            
                // NOT empty
                if ( ! empty( $order_refunds) ) {
                    // WIP need to check which items have tax
                    $total_to_refund = $order->get_total_refunded();
                
                    // Add fee
                    $cart->add_fee( 'Refund', $total_to_refund  );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_last_order_refund_total_at_checkout', 10, 1 );
```